# PHP Safari PushNotifications "Extracting push notification package failed"

Tags: javascript, php, safari

I'm trying to implement safari notifications and I have most things figure out. I'm following the official tutorial https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1  but I'm currently receiving the error:

> Extracting push notification package failed

I have seen this topic [APNs "Extracting push notification package failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264912/apns-extracting-push-notification-package-failed) but it seems the person didn't get any feedback / solution.

Before this error, I was getting "Signature verification of push package failed." but I endup solving the issue with this help [Apple website push: Signature verification of push package failed, but apple certificates are ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430205/apple-website-push-signature-verification-of-push-package-failed-but-apple-cer) and by downloading/converting to PEM the latest Apple certificate https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer

**Website.json** has the following data:

```
{
    "websiteName": "hello",
    "websitePushID": "web.com.hello",
    "allowedDomains": ["https://hello.com"],
    "urlFormatString": "https://hello.com/%@",
    "authenticationToken": "01sSggkfAAAqq1seeF0gglzzg",
    "webServiceURL": "https://hello.com"
}
```

**manifest.json** has the following data:

```
{
   "icon.iconset\/icon_16x16.png":{
      "hashType":"sha512",
      "hashValue":"d7366c75a9ad9a95ee2e6c6a4642ab6150d01986a870d8726e988c180e373cce7cbda1496150def585fb05e5b82d9753fabbe03e1e5bf56fce1c94a472bee50b"
   },
   "icon.iconset\/icon_16x16@2x.png":{
      "hashType":"sha512",
      "hashValue":"63287459ef021a8d3fe6a7ee40292446dddea305382713f25e8ff3f40b17d706012c809ebe6238a3652992ba55007f8dd22707b31f4730efc4b9d33baaca593d"
   },
   "icon.iconset\/icon_32x32.png":{
      "hashType":"sha512",
      "hashValue":"407027a704b967e57999d45ea68f2ccd156b49c698a4237ac8e60101f4c79388cbebf7242ac93c911f0176da49a49d12c5eec0f303943ea8f0d99f5d27898d21"
   },
   "icon.iconset\/icon_32x32@2x.png":{
      "hashType":"sha512",
      "hashValue":"a799fc64879d0d0304eb20b1bb96fe1c1b837e1cbc2d905ad3024b3230337d9f2a6ea41a73b02e91168b97fce13dd918f380d95ccd77ef1360e0bb818de8be99"
   },
   "icon.iconset\/icon_128x128.png":{
      "hashType":"sha512",
      "hashValue":"e709cbce5e4b4f355a4007a5665ad3b1b020ba81640fbed09db252910c20b956eab6167ae6a3e399b4b1f9ff1cf8eb4d68de844dd01a39d23fff15b3418ab6c5"
   },
   "icon.iconset\/icon_128x128@2x.png":{
      "hashType":"sha512",
      "hashValue":"1d210614b556267b6d41e1b7ad5d09db90ba77cab2196b85b7bc211873f03ebe3a89a0cf083b61181af0fa6900ba6eb8394f86e4921432a9779fb419c1def7ce"
   },
   "website.json":{
      "hashType":"sha512",
      "hashValue":"2c050ffb570fab3c4224ad2f08144f4ca9bf09d570f22bf3dc3cabf7c5146e436755bf171befcfa410d8f56ac4135b1e03b235197feed6306c5692b793b41668"
   }
}
```

My folder called "pushpackage" holds:

- website.json
- manifest.json
- signature
- icon.iconset folder > 6 images

Although the documentation says:

> The version of the API. Currently, 'v2'

the Safari requests are being made in the endpoint `https://hello.com/v1/pushPackages/web.com.hello`, which is kind of strange, but..

Lastly, the POST endpoint said above, triggers:

```
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pushpackage.zip"');

echo file_get_contents($file);
```

The zip seems fine - at least when I open all the files are correctly structured, but I'm out of ideas about what could be wrong with the zip file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**.

I had several things wrong in my code.

1. The error:

> Extracting push notification package failed

Was caused due to an `echo ...` in the middle of the code when creating the zip file.

2. The error:

> Signature verification of push package failed

Was caused due to several factors:

- My .p12 certificate was wrong, the .p12 `Website Push ID` did not match my `website.json` nor the javascript code. In order to debug / view the data of the certificate I used the command `openssl -nokeys -info -in certificate.p12 -passin pass:`
- The certificate AppleWWDRCAG3.cer (that expires in 2030) from the oficial link https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/ doesn't work. I had to download the file AppleWWDRCA.cer (that expires in 2023) from https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer
- My icons were not created in 72dpi resolution
- The version used by the Safari to request permissions is the version 1 "v1/pushPackages.." and I was creating the zip file with the `manifest.json` in the version 2

Comment: Had the same issue, AppleWWDRCAG3.cer didnt work, but AppleWWDRCA.cer did. Did you every work out why it doesnt work? 2023 is fast approaching...

Comment: @Gaz_Edge I did not. When 2023 comes, I'll worry about :D

Comment: Hey @Linesofcode I'm getting the same error "Extracting push notification package failed" but uncommenting & removing any echo not working. Can you please help here. Thanks

Comment: @Linesofcode sooner than you think - https://developer.apple.com/support/wwdr-intermediate-certificate/

Comment: @KhushiRaval did you find out any solution yet? I'm having the same issue but have no idea to fix it.

Comment: @ericlong The issue has been resolved for me but I don't have an exact idea as changes were done from the backend teammate maybe it was some issue of headers. I've asked him if he can reply to you with your query.

Comment: Thank you for replying. After days of researching, I found out my issue is that the webServiceURL in Website.json is not matching with the URL to request permission. My issue was solved.